# Why is a feedback loop not represented by the least order transfer function?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, transfer-function, z-transform

I have a feedback loop with transfer $L(z)= \frac{H(z)C(z)}{1+H(z)C(z)}$.

$$H(z) = h\quad \text{and} \quad C(z) = \frac{K}{z-\alpha}.$$

If I manually calculate the transfer function, I get:

$$L(z) = \frac{Kh}{z-\alpha + Kh}$$

But if I let MATLAB do the calculation I get:

$$L(z) = \frac{z-\alpha}{z-\alpha}\frac{Kh}{z-\alpha + Kh}$$

$L(z)$ is unstable with $\alpha=2$ and $K=\frac{1}{h}$. The second transfer function (calculated with MATLAB) has two poles $(1,2)$ of which one is outside the unit circle. So the second one seems to be correct. What is wrong with the first one?

Comment: What matlab function are you using?  There is a pole-zero cancellation in the matlab version of $L(z)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$L(z)$ is unstable", exactly?  The first TF looks correct to me.

Comment: @PeterK. I create z with tf('z', -1) and then just do C = K/(z-alpha) and L = H*C/(1+H*C).

Comment: @lxop with given values of K and alpha, the output of L is not bounded. For example step(L) will explode.

Comment: [According to the Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) `z = tf('z',-1)` means you've created a discrete time system with a sampling rate of -1. That seems wrong. Quote: `z = tf('z',Ts) to specify a TF model with sample time Ts using a rational function in the discrete-time variable, z.`

Comment: With those values of $K$, $\alpha$, and $h$, the first TF is $1/(z-1)$, which is unstable anyway with a pole on the unit circle.  Both versions of your TF give exactly the same step response (as could be expected).  I expect Matlab is just not doing any simplification when you create the feedback TF like you do.  Incidentally, when I use `feedback()` to create the fb TF, it gives me your first version.

Comment: You can use L=minreal(H*C/(1+H*C)) to avoid doing the pole-zero cancellation by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but let's work it out with $H(z) = h$ and $C(z) = \frac{K}{z-\alpha}$.:

$$
\begin{array}
\ L(z) &=& \frac{H(z)C(z)}{1+H(Z)C(z)}\\
&=& \frac{h \frac{K}{z-\alpha}}{ 1 + h \frac{K}{z-\alpha}}\\
&=& \frac{h K}{ z - \alpha + h K}\\
&=& \frac{h K}{ z - \alpha + h K}\ \ \frac{z - \beta}{ z - \beta}
\end{array}
$$

I added the last line to show what I mean by a pole-zero cancellation.  $\beta$ can be any value; if the pole and the zero at $\beta$ cancel out, the overall value of $\frac{z - \beta}{ z - \beta}$ is 1.

The trick will be to figure out why matlab inserts the extra $\frac{z - \alpha}{ z - \alpha}$ in there in the first plcae,